# Why does SSMS object explorer hide Azure SQL databases that Visual Studio shows?

Tags: azure-sql-database, ssms

I've an Azure SQL DB, created a few months ago, with a SQL Server style username and password as the only user (db admin)

When I connect to the server using SSMS, 2 out of the 3 databases on the server are not visible in Object Explorer. If I connect Visual Studio to the same server using the same username and password, all 3 show up as expected.

In SSMS if I manually type the DB name into the drop down at the top, it will switch to the invisible database and I can query it fine, including DML

Side by side screenshot:

[image]

On the left, SSMS showing one DB, on the right VS showing three. Also in the SSMS screenshot I've manually switched to one of the invisible DB that are visible in VS by typing its name and queried it. The data shown is the same as the "Show data" option visible in VS, so everything functionally seems to be the same between the two apps, other than the SSMS object explorer being incomplete.

If it's relevant, I note it takes an incredibly long time for VS to show anything past the list of databases; if, for example, I expand the `*****ternalReports` database node in VS then a spinning wheel will appear for at least 30, maybe 40 seconds before the list of tables loads. Same for showing the table data; VS will visually jam for 30 seconds before the data grid appears, then another long while before data renders into it

This slow behavior is true for any DB on the target server, whether it shows in SSMS or not. When VS is used to browse a local db performance is very quick.

Performance in SSMS is fine and quick; the single visible DB is listed quickly and expands to explore like any other Azure SQL instance I have. Querying Azure SQL via SSMS is much faster than it is in VS to return the same results.

There doesn't appear to be any filter set on the SSMS object explorer and SSMS is latest version, though the problem started on an earlier version that formerly worked well.

When I connect to the SQL Azure instance, if I hit "Options" I see that `<default>` is specified as the DB to connect to:

[image]

If I change this (by manual typing) to one of the invisible databases I know exists then SSMS will connect and the dropdown box at the top says whatever I've typed, but if I right click on the server node and choose "new query" the dropdown box at the top changes to be the sole visible database name

If, on the options screen, I change the "connect to database" option to be "Browse the server" I'm asked "This requires connection, proceed?" I say yes and then a dialog appears with all the DBs in:

[image]

Only other thing I can think of at the moment as being relevant is that this only happens with one of my SQL Azure server instances. The other 6 all behave perfectly well

Does anyone have any ideas what else I can try to debug this, or what might be the cause?

Comment: By any chance do you connect to a specific (default) non-system database when connecting with SSMS?

Comment: @ThomA added some info to the question, if it helps ?

Answer (score 0):

If you connect to the master database on the Azure SQL logical server, all databases on that server will be listed on SSMS.

[image]

If you specify a specific database on that dialog only that database will be listed on SSMS Object Explorer.

Make sure the login you are using to connect to the server has access to all databases. The login exist on the master database and a has corresponding user associated with the login on each Azure SQL database on that logical server.

Comment: This is true for my other 6 servers; if I choose some named database in the "connect to database", then I only see that one. If I choose `master` or `<default>` then I see all. However, for this one server, regardless of what I set the "connect to" setting to, be it *master*, *<default>* or any named database, the same one database called "...npr" always shows as the only DB on the server.. It's like what you say here, except the server is somehow "stuck" on that one database being set in the Connect To Database